# Programa NASM no suma ni da diferencia entre dos numeros como inputs

Tags: linux, base64, ensamblador, nasm

Soy principiante en Ensamblador y he estado tratando de implementar un codigo en NASM 64 bits que reciba dos numeros (de n digitos cada uno). Ambos son pasados por el algoritmo ATOI (Ascii to integer) y luego son sumados y tambien se busca la diferencia entre ellos. Y por ultimo se usa el algoritmo ITOA (Integer to Ascii) para poder imprimirlos en consola.

El problema con el que me encontre es que a la hora de imprimir los resultados. Este no imprime nada. A esto me refiero:

```
0
Ingrese el segundo numero: 123 
El resultado de la suma es: 
00
 y el resultado de la diferencia es: 

00
```

Si alguien sabe el como poder solucionar este problema, se lo agradeceria bastrate :)

Este es el codigo del programa:

````
    pedirNumUno db "Ingrese el primer numero: ", 0
    largoPedirUno equ $ - pedirNumUno

    pedirNumDos db "Ingrese el segundo numero: ", 0
    largoPedirDos equ $ - pedirNumDos

    mensajeDeSuma db "El resultado de la suma es: ", 0
    largoMensajeSuma equ $ - mensajeDeSuma

    mensajeDeDiferencia db " y el resultado de la diferencia es: ", 0
    largoMensajeDiferencia equ $ - mensajeDeDiferencia

    mensajeError db "Error en los valores ingresados.", 0
    largoError equ $ - mensajeError
    
    mensajeDebug db "Estoy aca!!!", 10
    largoDebug equ $ - mensajeDebug

    digitos db "0123456789ABCDEF"

section .bss
    numeroUno resb 21
    numeroDos resb 21
    resultadoDiferencia resb 21
    resultadoSuma resb 21

    resultado resb 21

section .text

    ;seccion de procedimientos y macros

;-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;Macro para depuracion
%macro debug 2
    push rax
    push rcx 
    push rdx      
    push rbx        
    push rbp        
    push rsi       
    push rdi
    push r10
    push r9
    push r8


    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, %1
    mov rdx, %2
    mov rax, 1
    syscall

    pop r8
    pop r9
    pop r10
    pop rdi
    pop rsi
    pop rbp
    pop rbx
    pop rdx
    pop rcx
    pop rax

%endmacro
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;Fin macro depuracion
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    global _start



_start:
    mov byte[resultado+20], 10
    mov byte[resultadoSuma+20], 10
    mov byte[resultadoDiferencia+20], 10
    ;Se pide numero 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, pedirNumUno
    mov rdx, largoPedirUno
    mov rax, 1
    syscall
    ;Se lee numero 1 y se guarda en rsi
    mov rdi, 0
    mov rsi, numeroUno
    mov rdx, 21
    mov rax, 0
    syscall

    
    mov rdi, numeroUno
    ;Se llama a atoi
    call atoi



    ;debug mensajeDebug, largoDebug

    mov [numeroUno], rax
    
    ;------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ;Inicio prueba de entrada/salida
    ;------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ;mov rax, [numeroUno]
    debug numeroUno,21
    mov rcx, resultado
    add rcx, 19
    mov rbx, 10
    call itoa
    debug resultado, 21
    ;jmp Fin_De_Programa
    ;------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ;Fin prueba entrada/salida
    ;------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ;Se pide numero 2
    
    ; Prueba Atoi y Itoa
    mov rdi, [resultado] ; Prueba
    call itoa            ; Prueba

    ;debug resultado, 21



    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, pedirNumDos
    mov rdx, largoPedirDos
    mov rax, 1
    syscall
    ;Se lee numero 2 y se guarda en numeroDos
    mov rdi, 0
    mov rsi, numeroDos
    mov rdx, 100
    mov rax, 0
    syscall

    mov rdi, rsi
    ;Se llama a atoi
    call atoi

    mov [numeroDos], rax



    ;call sumar
    
    ;call diferencia

    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, mensajeDeSuma
    mov rdx, largoMensajeSuma
    mov rax, 1
    syscall
    
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, resultadoSuma
    mov rdx, 100
    mov rax, 1
    syscall

    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, mensajeDeDiferencia
    mov rdx, largoMensajeDiferencia
    mov rax, 1
    syscall

    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, resultadoDiferencia
    mov rdx, 100
    mov rax, 1
    syscall
    
Fin_De_Programa:
    mov rax, 60
    xor rdi, rdi
    syscall

sumar:
    xor rsi, rsi
    xor rdx, rdx

    mov rsi, numeroUno
    mov rdx, numeroDos

    add rsi, rdx
    
    call itoa

    ret
diferencia:
    xor rsi, rsi
    xor rdx, rdx

    mov rsi, numeroUno
    mov rdx, numeroDos

    sub rsi, rdx
    
    mov rcx, [resultadoDiferencia]
    call itoa

    ret
; atoi: Convierte una cadena de dígitos en un número entero
; Argumentos:
;   RDI: Dirección de la cadena
; Retorna:
;   RAX: Número entero

atoi:
    xor     rax, rax       ; rax = 0
    xor     rcx, rcx       ; rcx = 0 (contador para el índice de la cadena)
    mov r12, 10
.loop:
    movzx   rdx, byte [rdi + rcx] ; Carga el siguiente byte de la cadena
    cmp     rdx, 10         ; Verifica si es el final de la cadena
    je      .done           ; Si es así, salta a la etiqueta done
    sub     rdx, '0'        ; Convierte el carácter a dígito
    mul r12                 ; Multiplica el número actual por 10
    add     rax, rdx       ; Suma el dígito al número
    inc     rcx            ; Incrementa el contador
    jmp     .loop          ; Repite el ciclo
.done:
    ret

; itoa: Convierte un número entero en una cadena de dígitos
; Posicion numero 20 hay que colocarle el 0Ah
; Argumentos:
;   RCX: Dirección de la cadena de destino + 19
;   RAX; Numero entero a convertir
;   RBX: Base numerica a la cual convertir
itoa:
    ;Inicializacion itoa original
    ;debug mensajeDebug, largoDebug

    ;mov     rcx, 10        ; rcx = 10 (para dividir por 10)
    ;mov     rbx, rsp       ; rbx = puntero al buffer de reversa
    ;add     rsp, 20        ; Reserva espacio en la pila para el buffer de reversa
    ;mov     byte [rbx + 20], 0 ; Establece el último byte del buffer en 0 (terminador de cadena)
    ;dec     rbx            ; Ajusta el puntero al buffer para escribir desde el final
    ;Fin inicializacion itoa original

    

.reverse_loop:
    ;debug mensajeDebug, largoDebug
    xor     rdx, rdx       ; rdx = 0 (para división)
    div     rbx            ; Divide rax por rbx y guarda el residuo en rbx 
    push rbx
    mov bl, byte[digitos+rdx]       ; Convierte el residuo a carácter
    mov byte[rcx], bl
    pop rbx
    dec     rcx            ; Avanza el puntero al buffer
    cmp    rax, 0       ; Verifica si el cociente es 0
    jne     .reverse_loop  ; Si no es 0, repite el ciclo

    ;mov     rsi, rsp       ; Actualiza el puntero a la cadena de destino
    ;sub     rax, rsi       ; Calcula la longitud de la cadena
    ;mov     rdx, rax       ; rdx = longitud de la cadena
    ;mov     rsi, rsp       ; rsi = puntero al buffer de reversa
    ;mov     rdi, rsi       ; rdi = puntero a la cadena de destino
    ;rep     movsb          ; Copia la cadena invertida al destino
    ;add     rsp, 20        ; Libera el espacio de la pila utilizado para el buffer de reversa
    ret
     ```
````

Comment: ¿Por qué asumes que el final de la cadena es 10? La función `read` no finaliza lo que leyó con un byte en específico. En lugar de leer 21 caracteres, considera leer 20 y manualmente establecer el último byte en 10 (o 0 que es lo más común).

Comment: Por cierto, otra forma de convertir un carácter a dígito es con una operación AND, solo tienes que usar una máscara con los 4 bits menos significativos en 1. `and rdx, 15`

Answer (score 1):

El código es un poco difícil de seguir ya que tienes un montón de líneas que no usas en tu programa. El código tiene dos problemas. Primero tu implementación de `atoi` tenía un error. Una posible forma de arreglarlo sería:

```
atoi:
    xor     rax, rax       ; rax = 0
    xor     rcx, rcx       ; rcx = 0 (contador para el índice de la cadena)
    mov     r12, 10
.loop:
    movzx   r8, byte [rdi + rcx] ; Carga el siguiente byte de la cadena
    cmp     r8, 10         ; Verifica si es el final de la cadena
    je      .done          ; Si es así, salta a la etiqueta done
    sub     r8, '0'        ; Convierte el carácter a dígito
    mul     r12            ; Multiplica el número actual por 10
    add     rax, r8        ; Suma el dígito al número
    inc     rcx            ; Incrementa el contador
    jmp     .loop          ; Repite el ciclo
.done:

    ret
```

El problema fundamental es que `mul` devuelve el resultado de la multiplicación en `RDX:RAX` borrando el contenido de RDX en el que almacenas el digito actual. Simplemente he utilizado otro registro.

La función `itoa` en principio parece funcionar aunque la implementación no parece ideal ya que el puntero en el que almacenas la cadena varia según la longitud del número.

El siguiente código después de leer el número funciona correctamente:

```
    mov rcx, resultado
    add rcx, 19
    mov rbx, 10

    call itoa
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi,1
;; Este valor apunta dentro de tu buffer a distintos lugares según el tamaño del número
    mov rsi,rcx  
    mov rdx, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, realmente me sirvió para solucionar mi error :)

Comment: De nada. Me alegro de que te haya servido :)